# Is there any best way to hide select option?

Tags: javascript, html, select

Is there any best way to hide an `option` in a `select` tag?
I want to hide some `option` in my `select` tag, for example

```
    <select>
      //number
      <option value="">-Please Select-</option>    
      <option class="number" value="1">1</option> 
      <option class="number" value="2">2</option> 
      <option class="number" value="3">3</option> 
      //English
      <option class="english" value="A">A</option> 
      <option class="english" value="B">B</option> 
      <option class="english" value="C">C</option> 
    </select>
<script>    
    var number = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
    var english = document.getElementsByClassName("english");

    if(show_enlish){
     for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
      number[i].style.display =  'none'; //hidden number 1 2 3
     }else{
      for (i = 0; i < english.length; i++) { 
      english[i].style.display =  'none'; //hidden english abc
     }
    }
</script>
```

I'm trying to use this code to hide the `option` tag.
Is there a best way to hide an `option` tag?

Comment: You can't hide `<option>` in some browsers, notably IE and Safari.  Choices are remove/replace or disable/enable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.getElementsByClassName('number')[0].remove();` (with index in loops or the `forEach()` prototype) to dynamically remove the items.

An updated loop from your code would be:

```js
for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    // keep using index 0 as the DOM array becomes smaller as you remove the element
    english[0].remove(); 
}
```

Or if you are using ES6, you may use `Array.from()` to turn the `NodeList` to an array then use `forEach()`:

```js
Array.from(english).forEach(element => {
    element.remove();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use visibility css property....

*visibility: visible|hidden|collapse|initial|inherit;*

or create a className called hide

```
.hide{
visbibility:hidden;
}
```

then add the className to option using JS

Answer (score -1):

Beside the fact that you can't hide  in some browsers, like IE and Safari.
you can use Jquery and get some nicer code like this

```
$('<someSelector>').change(function(){
    if(number){
        $('.english').addClass('hide');
        $('.number').removeClass('hide');
    }else{
        $('.number').addClass('hide');
        $('.english').removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```